# swiper is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have code above like this but every time use this method i get error

> cggowl_jav_info_cont.swiper us not a function

i am not able to figure out why, please help

```
var cggowl_jav_info_cont = $scope.find('.cggowl-row').eq(0);
var cgggowl_settings = cggowl_jav_info_cont.data('settings');
var cgggowl_slidesPerView = cgggowl_settings['slidesPerView'];


cggowl_jav_info_cont.swiper('.swiper-container', {
                          slidesPerView: cgggowl_slidesPerView,
});
```

For slick slider like above the method works

```
var cggowl_jav_info_cont = $scope.find('.cggowl-row').eq(0);
var cgggowl_settings = cggowl_jav_info_cont.data('settings');
var cgggowl_slidesPerView = cgggowl_settings['slidesPerView'];


cggowl_jav_info_cont.slick({
                          slidesPerView: cgggowl_slidesPerView,
});
```

if i use var `myCar = new swiper('.swiper-container', {` the carousel will work.

Comment: Did you include this "swiper" library in your code?

Comment: @David yes i have it works if i use new ..but this method does not seem to work. Slick slider was initiated this way `cggowl_jav_info_cont.swiper` it works

Comment: It's not really clear from that comment what "works" and what "doesn't work".  Can you provide a more complete example of the problem?  Include the HTML, importing the libraries, etc.  You are encouraged to make use of Code Snippets in your question to create executable and demonstrable examples of HTML/CSS/JS questions.

Comment: @David Hi, I have added the details to question. Html structure is the same as the swiper documentation

Comment: Just create a snippet that reproduces your problem. That way people are more eager to help.

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla: Just because you’ve imported one library and can use it does not necessarily mean some other library will work.  Please take the time to provide a complete example which demonstrates the problem and include a link to the documentation for the exact function you are trying to call.

Comment: @David okay. This involved the wordpress so there is a lot of code. let me try to replicate this with codepen.

Comment: @MarkBaijens This involved the wordpress so there is a lot of code. let me try to replicate this with codepen.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import [swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/) in your proyect

Comment: import swiper before your script.

Comment: Yes, i have imported it but the above method does not work. I have updated the question with mode details